# What is wrong with my one line prime function in java?

Tags: java, primes, conditional-operator

**EDIT**

I'd like to create a java program that outputs all the prime numbers smaller than a given number `n` prompted as input to the user. The challenge is to write a function that will do this **in one line**. It does not make it a better code but still remains an interesting challenge.

I start with my `main` method where I ask the user for input and pass it as a parameter for my `Primes(int number, int divisor)` method. This method takes two parameters, `number` and `divisor`. The method checks if `number` is divisible by the `divisor`. If the latter doesn't divide the former, the method calls itself again with `divisor = divisor - 1` until the `the divisor = 1`. Hurray, we've found a prime number. Therefore, I have to print it **AND** have to call my method again with `number = number - 1` and the `divisor = number - 2`. I must do so because I've got to check for every prime smaller than `number`.

`Primes(number-1, number-2)`.

Is it possible for a method to return a value **AND** to call another method at the same time? I'd need something like this:

```java
    ...condition ? do smth : return n && Primes(smth)...
```

Please tell me if I wasn't clear enough.
Thanks in advance,

Here's my code. It looks weird but it's really straightforward if you take your time to look at it :

```
 import java.*;
 import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static int Primes(int n, int k) {
        return ((k == 0) ? n : (k == 1 && n == 1) 
                         ? n : (k == 1 && n > 1) 
                         ? Primes(n-1, n-2) : (n % k) != 0 
                         ? Primes(n, k-1) : Primes(n-1, n-2));
    }
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num = s.nextInt();
        System.out.println("The primes are: " + Primes(num, (num-1)));
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you think is good about writing it on one line?

Comment: Code isn't better just because it is written on one line, write readable code instead so you can read it and understand it.

Comment: holy moly that conditional is...something else...maybe go with some plain ol if/else blocks

Comment: `k == 0` -> `n*893953` is not prime (unless calculation overflows); `k == 1 && n == 1` -> `n`, which is `1`, also not a prime; otherwise recursive call (ending with one of the 2 previous values, not prime) Another problem `Primes` is returning one single value.

Comment: What is the meaning of the `n` and `k` parameters and what is the meaning of the return value of the `Primes()` method? Also, you are not printing anywhere any prime numbers.

Comment: Ok I see what's not clear. I'll put it differently. Oh and @joakim-danielson the one line function is just a challenge I set myself.

Comment: @HTMLator What is the question you have? It looks like it calculates the greatest factor for each number you are checking, but you are not doing anything with that information. And how are you supposed to sneak a `System.out.println()` inside the ternary operator chain to output the primes you have found?

Comment: @Progman _And how are you supposed to sneak a System.out.println() inside the ternary operator chain to output the primes you have found?_ That is my question

Comment: @Kirby: Takes your breath away, doesn't it? :)

Comment: @AndyTurner It's all about the challenge

Comment: @sleepydrmike there's no challenge in writing code in one line, you just remove all the line breaks.

Comment: @AndyTurner With `one line`, I meant one semicolon. Anyway, you can see this is a very simple program. Highschool homework. Without the `one line` challenge, it wouldn't be very interesting. Anyway, can you look at my answer ? Since the downvote, I can't answer anything on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kind of found a solution to my challenge. Look if you're interested, although I know it's not optimal. Since I couldn't find a way to `return n && Primes(smth)`, I made a new method `PrintPrimes(int n)` that would print `n` and call `Primes(n-2, n-3)`. Here it is:

```
import java.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
    
public class Main {
    
  public static int Primes(int n, int k) {
    // Check if k and n are lower than 2 we're done because we've checked every number from n all the way down to 1
    // If k is 1 and n is greater than 1 we've found a prime and have to print it
    // If n modulo k yields 0 then n is not prime. We call the method again with n = n - 1
    // If n mod k is different than 0, we call the method again with k = k - 1
    
    return ((k < 2 && n < 2) ? PrintPrimes(n) : (k == 1 && n > 1) 
                             ? PrintPrimes(n) : (n % k) != 0 
                             ? Primes(n, k-1) : Primes(n-1, n-2));
    }
        
    public static int PrintPrimes(int n) {
            System.out.println(n);
            return ((n == 1) ? n : Primes(n-2, n-3));
    }
        
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            
     Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
     int num = s.nextInt();
     Primes(num, (num-1));
    }
    
}
```

And this works pretty well